# Nuget Package Without Lib-Ref-Content Folders

Tags: nuget

I have downloaded an open source project, made changes to it and then created a nuget package from this new code. The package actually functions as a post-build target. It just runs an exe. That is why it does not contain a `lib` folder. There is a `tools` folder and files are copied under this folder. The other folders are: `build`, `buildCrossTargeting`, `package`, `_rels`. .But when I try to install this local nuget package to a .net 4.6.1 project, I get the following error in Visual Studio:

> You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework.

When I open and inspect the original nuget package downloaded from nuget.org, I see the same structure. But somehow it installs fine while this locally created one raises error.

What can be done about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information you provided, I can only guess (please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). My guess is that you changed the name (id) of the package, but didn't change the name of the target or props files in the build directory. [As the docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#including-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package), the name of the targets and props file must match the package id exactly, so if you change the package id, you must rename those files.